# Bootstrap columns overlap when window is shrunk

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have looked around at other posts and I can not seem to find the answer to this.

I am trying to make a webpage with Bootstrap. I want a vertical nabvar fixed on the left that takes up 3 columns and content on the right that takes up 9 columns. I have implemented scrollspy to update the navbar when scrolling.

It works perfectly until I shrink the screen. My understanding is that it should put the columns on top of each other. If I remove the affix property from the column, it updates correctly, but the navbar is not fixed so scrollspy is pointless.

Here is my code:

```css
ul.nav-pills {
  padding-top: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.item {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

#content {
  margin-bottom: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Meet Sarah</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sarah.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="content" class="row">
      <nav class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
        <ul class="nav  nav-pills nav-stacked  " data-spy="affix">
          <li class="active snav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about_me">About Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#school">Colorado School of Mines</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#alpine">Alpine Ski Racing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#music">Music</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#outreach">Outreach</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#extra">Extracurriculars</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#likes">Obsessions</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="about_me" class="container-fluid item">
          <h1>About Me</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        </div>

        <div id="school" class="container-fluid item">
          <h1>Colorado School of Mines</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        </div>

        <div id="alpine" class="container-fluid item">
          <h1>Alpine Ski Racing</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        </div>

        <div id="music" class="container-fluid item">
          <h1>Music</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        </div>

        <div id="outreach" class="container-fluid item">
          <h1>Outreach</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        </div>

        <div id="extra" class="container-fluid item">
          <h1>Extracurriculars</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        </div>

        <div id="likes" class="container-fluid item">
          <h1>Obsessions</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix my left-hand navbar without it overlapping in a smaller screen?

Comment: why are you using `data-spy="affix"` in your `nav-pills` ul..?

Comment: To fix it to the top when scrolling down on the screen. I want to be able to see it no matter how far down on the screen you have scrolled. I had a position: fixed property for it in the css, but my research suggest against that.

Comment: use `xs` instead of  `sm` in your cols...I hope this will fix...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But that didn't seem to change anything...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "col-sm-9" to "col-md-9" or "col-lg-9". Whichever works better. Or Use "col-9".

```
  ...
  <div class="col-9">
    <div id="about_me" class="container-fluid item">
      <h1>About Me</h1>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
      <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    </div>
    ...
```